# Nginx Location Block Access List and 'X-Forwarded-For'

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, x-forwarded-for

I have a few wordpress sites on a Load Balanced Nginx Cluster. I wish to block access to /wp-admin and /wp-login.php on these. The client is not willing to use a plugin such as Wordfence to achieve this (understandably).

The Load Balancers forward the real client IP within X-Forwarded-For, and this is present within Nginx, as I currently use it in my main log format with **"$http_x_forwarded_for"**.

This is my current location block:

```
   location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php) {

     real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     index index.html index.htm index.php;

     root           /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/html;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include        fastcgi_params;

     allow 1.1.1.1;
     allow 2.2.2.2;
     allow 3.3.3.3;
     #allow 10.10.85.0/24;
     deny all;
   }
```

As you can see, I use **"real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;"** to declare what the real ip should be. But this does not work. With the above in place, ALL requests to there are blocked. If I uncomment the private **10.10.85.0/24** subnet (which is the private network that traffic is delivered on FROM the load balancers), then access to the locations is granted for EVERYONE.

I do have the realip module compiled in Nginx, as can be seen here:

```
[root@STR-MAI-ORDS1 conf.d]# 2>&1 nginx -V | tr -- - '\n' | grep http_realip_module
http_realip_module
[root@STR-MAI-ORDS1 conf.d]#
```

In my log files, I can see the real public IP being printed to log through use of X-Forwarded-For, but the same does not work for this location block realip, and I'm not sure why.

If it matters, the environment looks like this:

- pfSense FW (2 node HA)
- Zevenet Load Balancer (2 node HA)
- CentOS 6.x Web Server (3 node cluster)

The web stack is:

- Nginx v1.12.0
- PHP-FPM v7.0.20 (fastcgi)

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be great. Thanks.

Comment: [this looks related](https://superuser.com/questions/960454/how-do-i-use-allow-deny-in-conjunction-with-set-real-ip-from). Be aware that ajax functions use /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php as a backend for both privileged and anonymous users.

Comment: @janh - Related enough to kick me into realising what I'd done wrong, yes. Thanks for that. Turns out "set_real_ip_from" is required, not optional. Nginx doesnt trust setting its real ip to a header that came form somewhere else unless you tell it to trust that source with "set_real_ip_from". +1 to you.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out "set_real_ip_from" within Nginx is not optional... Even though I was correctly setting the "real_ip_header" to "X-Forwarded-For form the LoadBalancers, Nginx was completely refusing to do so because it doesn't (by default) trust the LB as a source that can set the real IP.

The fix was to include the following within my location block:

```
set_real_ip_from 10.10.85.0/24;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Then Nginx trusts the LB (which is within that subnet) and sets the real-ip to that.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a config file for multiple blockings as below.

modify ngnix config file

```
vi /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

include new config file for blocking the IPs inside nginx.conf

```
include blockips.conf;
```

save the ngnix config file and create the new file

```
vi blockips.conf
```

add your blacklisted IPs

```
deny 1.2.3.4;
```

or subnet blocking

```
deny 91.212.45.0/24;
```

for more information see [nginx Blocking IP](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/)
and for [subnet](https://superuser.com/questions/158291/whats-the-meaning-of-10-0-0-1-24-address-of-my-computer-ip-addr-command)

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.